# Problem in changing text of button in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a script

```
import tkinter as tk

class Btn_maker:
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window
        self.num = 0
        self.matrix = [[],[],[]]
    def btn_maker(self,cmd,x=1,y=1,padx=5,pady=5):
        self.btn = tk.Button(self.window,command = cmd,width = 6,height = 2)
        Btn_maker.btn_grid(self,x,y,padx,pady)
    def btn_grid(self,x,y,padx,pady):
        self.btn.grid(row = x, column = y, padx = padx, pady = pady)
    def game_logic(self,x,y):
        self.num+=1
        if self.num%2==1:
            self.btn.config(text = 'X')
        else:
            self.btn.config(text = 'O')
        #self.matrix[x-1][y-1] 
    
window = tk.Tk()
frame1 = tk.Frame(window)
frame1.pack()
label = tk.Label(frame1,text='Game',fg='red',font = 30)
label.pack()
frame2 = tk.Frame(window)
frame2.pack()
btn_instant = Btn_maker(frame2)
btn1 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(1,1),x=1,y=1)
btn2 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(1,2),x=1,y=2)
btn3 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(1,3),x=1,y=3)
btn4 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(2,1),x=2,y=1)
btn5 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(2,2),x=2,y=2)
btn6 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(2,3),x=2,y=3)
btn7 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(3,1),x=3,y=1)
btn8 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(3,2),x=3,y=2)
btn9 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(3,3),x=3,y=3)
window.geometry('200x300')
window.mainloop()
```

It works but when I press to button it change text of the last button but I need to change the button's text which I pressed

[It looks like when I run program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozXt7.png)
When I click to the first button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNREe.png)

Comment: So this is a TicTacToe Game and Your issue is when press any button only the last (3,3) button changes right?

Answer (score 1):

you are not returning `self.btn` in btn_maker
code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Btn_maker:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.num = 0
        self.matrix = [[], [], []]

    def btn_maker(self, cmd, x=1, y=1, padx=5, pady=5):
        btn = tk.Button(self.window, command=cmd, width=6, height=2)
        btn.grid(row=x, column=y, padx=padx, pady=pady)  # Grid the button directly
        return btn  # Return the created button

    def game_logic(self, btn, x, y):
        self.num += 1
        if self.num % 2 == 1:
            btn.config(text='X')
        else:
            btn.config(text='O')

window = tk.Tk()
frame1 = tk.Frame(window)
frame1.pack()
label = tk.Label(frame1, text='Game', fg='red', font=30)
label.pack()
frame2 = tk.Frame(window)
frame2.pack()
btn_instant = Btn_maker(frame2)
btn1 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(btn1, 1, 1), x=1, y=1)
btn2 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(btn2, 1, 2), x=1, y=2)
btn3 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(btn3, 1, 3), x=1, y=3)
btn4 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(btn4, 2, 1), x=2, y=1)
btn5 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(btn5, 2, 2), x=2, y=2)
btn6 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(btn6, 2, 3), x=2, y=3)
btn7 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(btn7, 3, 1), x=3, y=1)
btn8 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(btn8, 3, 2), x=3, y=2)
btn9 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(btn9, 3, 3), x=3, y=3)
window.geometry('200x300')
window.mainloop()
```

after fixing that your code should work properly

result:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
 def btn_maker(self, cmd, x=1, y=1, padx=5, pady=5):
    self.btn = tk.Button(self.window, command=cmd, width=6, height=2)
    self.btn_grid(self.btn, x, y, padx, pady) 
 def game_logic(self, x, y):
        btn = self.matrix[x-1][y-1]
        self.num += 1
        if self.num % 2 == 1:
            btn.config(text='X')
        else:
            btn.config(text='O')
 def btn_grid(self, btn, x, y, padx, pady):
    btn.grid(row=x, column=y, padx=padx, pady=pady)
```

update these two functions then try

Comment: `btn_grid()` need to be changed as well for your solution.

Comment: def btn_grid(self, btn, x, y, padx, pady):
        btn.grid(row=x, column=y, padx=padx, pady=pady)

Comment: it throws error `File "d:/pgm/python/pratice/test.py", line 31, in <module>
    btn1 = btn_instant.btn_maker(lambda: btn_instant.game_logic(1,1),x=1,y=1)
  File "d:/pgm/python/pratice/test.py", line 11, in btn_maker
    self.btn_grid(btn, x, y, padx, pady)
TypeError: btn_grid() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given`

Comment: mismatch in the number of arguments passed to the btn_grid() method                             def btn_grid(self, btn, x, y, padx, pady):  
 btn.grid(row=x, column=y, padx=padx, pady=pady)

Comment: also add def btn_maker(self, cmd, x=1, y=1, padx=5, pady=5):
        self.btn = tk.Button(self.window, command=cmd, width=6, height=2)
        self.btn_grid(self.btn, x, y, padx, pady)

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I think it is better to update your answer.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer. Line 15, in game_logic
    btn = self.matrix[x-1][y-1]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: due to same line comment the first one